# Is there a way to call Silverlight method from Asp.net MVC4 controllder?

Tags: silverlight, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to call Silverlight method from my MVC4 application controller.

I load Silverlight using object tag,

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="50%" height="100%" style="border:1px solid #cdcdcd">
          <param name="source" value="ClientBin/HelloWorld.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <param name="onLoad" value="pluginLoaded" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
```

and to call Silverlight method, I'm using JS method.

BUT I want to call silverlight method from MVC4-controllder.

Is it possible? if so, How should I do?

please advice me.

```
//Silverlight method
[ScriptableMember]
public void ShowAlertPopup(string message)
{
    MessageBox.Show(message, "Message From JavaScript", MessageBoxButton.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is impossible. Silverlight runs on the client as well as JavaScript, while MVC runs on the server. These are different machines.

If you need to reuse a method, you could use either of:

1. [Source code sharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9f4t9t92.aspx) (section 'Adding an Existing Item as a Link')
2. [Portable Library project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx)
3. [RIA Services Shared Code features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707371%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)

If the only thing you need is reusing a couple of methods, I suggest moving them to a separate file and then linking the file to 2 projects (a MVC project and a Silverlight project).

One important note is that you can only reuse code that uses features present both in Silverlight and .NET. You can't use Silverlight-specific features (e.g. browser interaction) from an MVC application.

---

If you need to send messages from your server to your client, you have to implement either of:

1. Polling
2. Long polling
3. Server-Sent events
4. WebSockets

[SignalR](http://signalr.net/) is a great library for simplifying the task.